# Remove package files from previous Ubuntu installation

Tags: apt, package-management, disk-usage, reinstall

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu (actually updated from 16.10 to 17.10) and while my Home directory is intact, any packages that were installed by me earlier are gone (not installed). *However, it seems that their files are still on the disk*. For example, I have the package `zsh` installed earlier, and now it's not installed. Still, there is a `/usr/share/zsh` folder containing lots of files.

I actually like the idea of starting from scratch with my packages, but I'm low on disk space. How can I completely remove all files leftover from the packages of the previous installation, without erasing any files needed for currently installed packages?

Comment: That will probably require you to scan practically every directory in `/usr`, `/var`, etc. It will  be prohibitively expensive and possibly harmful, since some files might be generated and not included in the package file list.

Comment: Well, what's the best I could do? Could I at least go by folders in `/usr`, /usr/share`, `/var`... how do I know which ones are not used, and where else to look? It's OK if I don't catch exactly everything.

Comment: Run `dpkg -S /path/to/folder`. If it's included in the filelist of an installed package, `dpkg` will report it.

Comment: Ok, that's a start, I'll do that. And what locations might be relevant to look at, except for example `/usr/share`?

Comment: In `/`, `/usr` except `/usr/local`, places in `/var` like `/var/lib`, the `/lib*` directories, `/sbin` and `/bin`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that looks like a complete list. However, since you mentioned `/`... It's it not possible that the might be other system-critical folders there that just aren't packages?

Comment: I said *In `/`* ... what I meant was starting from there, look in those folders only. Leave the others alone.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thank you. Feel free to make an answer.

Comment: You can avoid this situation by purging rather than removing unwanted packages. See `man apt-get` - remove "Note that removing a package leaves its
           configuration files on the system." vs purge "purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
           purged (any configuration files are deleted too)." Also, in your case "I actually like the idea of starting from scratch with my packages, but I'm low on disk space." in that case a fresh install is easier and faster than cleaning up. If you know the offending packages you can install and then purge them.

Comment: @Panther I don't know the offending packages, and as I said, I did reinstall the system, but somehow a lot of package folders are still present.